# Silverlight UI Automation of a Child Window and its controls?

Tags: silverlight, ui-automation

I have trouble to make UI Automation of the Child Windows. I cannot trace any element inside any child window in the project. I am using UISpy.  I set AutomationProperties.AutomationId for all of items inside ChildWindows.

I am hoping to find the answer on thos topic. There is no much documentation on it or I was not able to find it. Any sample or ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't good automation support for Popups in Silverlight at this time. Popups are not considered part of the main visual tree, so they are effectively disconnected. ChildWindows are shown in a Popup, so they are effectively disconnected as well.

[Here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/36899/108324.aspx#108324) is one possible solution, which basically tracks the popups/child windows and injects them as automation children of the parent page.

Apparently, [Telerik](http://blogs.telerik.com/testing/posts/10-05-19/silverlight_childwindow_and_popup_support_in_webui_test_studio_and_webaii_testing_framework.aspx) also has a solution for their test suite, with a video [here](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/videos/silverlight-automation/silverlight-child-windows-and-popups.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunatelly, we cannot use Telerik's test suite. Thank you a lot for your helpful information. I will look for more information but it is a great starting point for me.